# apex chart legend in multiple lines / line break

Tags: visualforce-charting

I have 10 line series apex chart developed in visual force page. I am displaying my legend at bottom of the chart. I dont see all the legends being shown. The legend is shown as on single line and starting and end legends are missing (hidden). Is there any way we can break this single line legend into multiple lines.

My current chart looks like below, it contains 10 Companies, but it doesnt show all of them in single line. I have taken look at apex:legend attributes, none to be helping.

[image]